# Several alternative affiliations in achemso

Tags: achemso, affiliation

I need to have 2 "altaffiliation" for an author using `achemso`, meaning:

```
\author{author1}
\affiliation{uni1}
\altaffiliation{Contributed equally to this work}
\author{author2}
\affiliation{uni1}
\altaffiliation{Present address: uni2}
\altaffiliation{Contributed equally to this work}
```

Once compiled, the two footnotes appear but the symbol corresponding to the present address next to Author #2 is absent. How can I fix this? The documentation or Google says nothing about it.

Answer (score 6):

`achemso` manual states this:

> Repeated entries for \affiliation and \alsoaffiliation will result in only
>   one address being printed in the address list and footnotes. Repeated
>   \altaffiliation entries only produce a single footnote, and can therefore be
>   used for entries such as

```
\author{First Coworker}
\altaffiliation{Contributed equally to this work}
\author{Second Coworker}
\altaffiliation{Contributed equally to this work}
```

> if required.

Therefore, you should better use `alsoaffiliation` for the second address like this:

```
\documentclass{achemso}
\title{Title}
\author{author1}
\affiliation{uni1}
\alsoaffiliation{Present address: uni2}
\altaffiliation{Contributed equally to this work}
\author{author2}
\affiliation{uni1}
\alsoaffiliation{Present address: uni2}
\altaffiliation{Contributed equally to this work}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that but the general layout is then changed. The text in `altaffiliation` should come at the end, after all the `affiliation` and `alsoaffiliation` declarations. In my case, I have 3 authors. What you suggest adds the present address between author2's past address and author3's address whereas "Contributed equally to this work" and author2's past address should come after author3's address.